# Simple google sheet trade summary from Tradingview .csv file

Tags: csv, google-sheets-formula, tradingview-api, summary

I have this raw data in this format: [image: list of filled orders]

I want to add a column (or more than one if it’s not possible to find a single formula to complete the job) that matches each open trade by instrument and chronological order with the related closing trade.

For example, row 21 opens a short position on MESH24, 1 lot, at 4762 (column H).
The next action is row 20, where the short is covered at 4760, resulting in a 2-point profit.
In this case, the rows are subsequent, but they could be distributed differently, like for example row 5 that opens a short that is closed in row 2.

---

I'm sorry: I posted in a hurry and I did not know I had to elaborate more.
It's two weeks I am trying to find a formula with a simple logic: since the rows are in chronological order, you always encounter first the opening trade. For instance, if you come across a buy on symbol X, the formula must then locate a sell on the same symbol at a later time.

Following the FIFO criteria, the first opposite order you find for the same instrument will close your initial open position, irrespective of any other open positions on the same or different instruments.

After numerous tries the best I could come with is this: "=IF(AND(B2="Buy", B3="Sell", A2=A3), D2-D3, IF(AND(B2="Sell", B3="Buy", A2=A3), D3-D2, ""))" as a helper column for these data: [image: opening and closing orders].

All is ok if the opening and closing rows defining a trade are adjacent, but if they are not the formula does not work because check for the closing order only on subsequent rows.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: I created this file with some notes: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XWFk_8yI3Bh2MBs_Tkrj7TawNc3JrbkppmoDvhK0O6I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: please do add the expected output for more number of **rows** (along with the non-sequential ones you are referring to)

Comment: done. I added also some more explanations in notes.

Answer (score 1):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=map(A2:A,B2:B,D2:D,lambda(Σ,Λ,Ξ,if(isodd(countif(A2:Σ,Σ))+(Σ=""),,if(Λ="Buy",-1,1)*((Ξ-xlookup(Σ,A2:offset(Σ,-1,),D2:offset(Ξ,-1,),,,-1))*switch(mid(Σ,6,3),"MES",4,"MNQ",4,"MGC",10,"M6E",10000,1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the incredible solution! IT works perfectly until it encounters two consecutive open trades on the same instrument in A53. I added a new sheet "solution" and completed the manual calculations. I did not mention MCL: I tried to do this: "MES",4,"MNQ",4,"MGC",10,"MCL",10,"M6E",10000,1) but it did not work. In C84, the quantity is 2, not 1: I don't know how it's possible. Without that double size, it would not be possible to close the two shorts on M6E opened in row 77 and 83. To calculate the total PNL of that trade I just added the two results: =10000*(D77-D84)+10000*(D83-D84)